# How to find the average value for a combination of columns in R

Tags: r, combinations, average

I have the Following Dataset:

```
A B C
1 2 6
3 2 5
1 2 4
3 2 7
2 2 3
```

I want to be able to find the average value of C based on the combination of A and B. So basically I want to have the Following dataset as a result :

```
A B Avr_C
1 2 5
3 2 6
2 2 3
```

Any idea on how to proceed ? Thank you.

Comment: `aggregate(C~A + B, df, mean)` or with `dplyr`, `df %>% group_by(A, B) %>% summarise(Avr_C = mean(C))`

Comment: Thank you I tried aggregate and it worked